# MS Access SQL Case When expression

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, case-when

I am trying to convert a block of code from SQL Server Management Studio to an Access Database and am having some trouble with my Case When expressions.

What am I missing in the Case When below so it is compatible with MS Access Queries?

```
Case WHEN E.MemberStartDate <= "2018-01-01 AND E.MemberEndDate >= "2018-12-31" 
THEN "" 
WHEN "2018-01-01" <= E.MemberEndDate AND "2018-01-31" >= 
E.MemberStartDate THEN "X" ELSE "" END AS Cov1Jan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with *IIf* and *octothorpes* (#):

```
IIf(E.MemberStartDate <= #2018/01/01 AND E.MemberEndDate >= #2018/12/31#, 
    Null,
    IIf(#2018/01/01# <= E.MemberEndDate AND #2018/01/31# >= E.MemberStartDate, 
        "X", 
        Null)) AS Cov1Jan
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing that MS-Access doesn't support `case`.  So:

```
switch(E.MemberStartDate <= "2018-01-01 AND E.MemberEndDate >= "2018-12-31", "", 
       "2018-01-01" <= E.MemberEndDate AND "2018-01-31" >= 
E.MemberStartDate, "X"
       1=1, "") AS Cov1Jan
```